# Create Tree view using different symbols like rectangle , circle and hexagon based on condition

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to create a treeview/flowchart in d3 and i am very new to d3 js.

Tree has a nodes with different symbol , but not sure how to create rectangle,hexagon symbol dynamically and append it to tree node.

I am trying something like this: http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8375092

Comment: where are you stuck? what have you tried?

Comment: i am able to create multiple symbols using inbuilt symbols, but rectangle and hexagon are not part of it, i am stuck while creating these 2 new symbols.
I am able to create tree view but i want to use different symbols on different nodes based on conditions.

Comment: replace the circle element creation with the creation of the element you want.

Comment: @RobertLongson i am able to replace circle with only inbuilt symbols, not sure how to create symbols like rectangle and hexagon

Comment: rect: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/rect; hexagon: http://jsfiddle.net/LJuRp/

Comment: http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html#rect

Comment: my code looks like this : 
node.append("path")
          .classed("outer",true)
          .attr("d", d3.symbol()
            .type(function(d){
              if(d.data.class === "startnode" || d.data.class === "endnode"){
                return d3.symbolCircle;
              }
              else if(d.data.class === "engnode"){
                return d3.symbolSquare;
              }
              return d3.symbolCircle;
            })
            .size(44*100)
          );

Comment: @ChiragKothari thanks for the help,

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks for the doc, really helpful . i will try and update whether i can achieve it.